# How to select chats from Message table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple Message Table.

```
FROM|TO|DATETIME|MSG
----|--|--------|---
    |  |        |
```

Given a user, I want to select the chats. For example:

```
FROM|TO|DATETIME|MSG
----|--|--------|---
 A  |B |    1   | x
 B  |A |    2   | x
 B  |A |    3   | x
 A  |B |    4   | x
 C  |A |    8   | x
```

I want to select the chats of A (The last chat that A has sent or received for each other user).

```
FROM|TO|DATETIME|MSG
----|--|--------|---
 C  |A |    8   | x
 A  |B |    4   | x
```

This is what I've got

```
create procedure GetMessageHeaders
    @user varchar(30)
as
    with msg as
    (
        select M.transmitter,M.receiver
        from "MESSAGE" M
        where M.receiver=@user or M.transmitter=@user
        order by M.DATE desc
    )
    select *
    from msg
```

Comment: within the cte, you can't order.  you can `Select top 1 * from message order by msg.date`. Does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a simpler way but the following produces the desired result. We first produce a combined recordset of chats we started and chats we received, then we work out a row number per "other" party, then we filter out only one row per other party.

```
declare @Message table ([From] varchar(1), [To] varchar(1), [DateTime] int, msg varchar(1));

insert into @Message ([From], [To], [DateTime], msg)
  select 'A', 'B', 1, 'x'
  union all
  select 'B', 'A', 2, 'x'
  union all
  select 'B', 'A', 3, 'x'
  union all
  select 'A', 'B', 4, 'x'
  union all
  select 'C', 'A', 8, 'x'

select [From], [To], [DateTime], Msg
from (
  select *
    -- Calculate a row number per other party by time
    , row_number() over (partition by case when [Type] = 0 then [To] else [From] end order by [DateTime] desc) Row#
  from (
    -- Get chats we initiated
    select 0 [Type], [From], [To], [DateTime], Msg
    from @Message
    where [From] = 'A'
    union all
    -- Get chats we recevied
    select 1 [Type], [From], [To], [DateTime], Msg
    from @Message
    where [To] = 'A'
  ) X
) Y
where Row# = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I would think something along these lines would work. You need first instance of each grouping ordered chronologically desc.

```
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            LastInstanceReversed = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FROM,TO ORDER BY DATETIME DESC)
        FROM
            Message
    )AS X
    WHERE
        X.LastInstanceReversed=1
```

Comment: That includes a duplicate party B when they both received and initiated a chat

Comment: Well, you beat me too it. I knew one way was to UNION ALL prior to serializing but you checked your answer in just before I was going to submit the edit here. I will leave mine as is.

Comment: Oh, I am confused now. Your solution answers the original question correctly. @Cthulhu, please check the answer from Dale Burrell as he pointed out something I overlooked in my answer.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I learned a lot from your answers. The solution by Ross gave a repeated pair, but it needed just a simple fix. The solution by Dale was correct as it is.